# PHP subtracting a week from two existing date variables

Tags: php

PHP 7.1.7

I have a custom work processing week that runs from Saturday through Friday.  For the code below, I'm selecting the current processing week where the $current_date is '08/25/2017' and that returns a range of '08/19/2017' (Saturday) to '08/25/2017' (Friday).

What I'm trying to do now is to get the previous work processing week.  With '08/19/2017' selected, that should be '08/12/2017' through '08/18/2017'.

I'm confused as to why, when I'm subtracting 1 week from the $Saturday and $Friday dates, the new 'previous working week' variables are off.

The output of the php is:

> This Reporting Week: 08/19/2017 to 08/25/2017
>
> Previous Reporting Week: 12/31/1969 to 12/31/1969

```
<?php
#------------ WORKING -------------------------
$current_date = "08/25/2017";

if(date("l", strtotime($current_date)) == "Saturday"){
    $Saturday = strtotime($current_date);
}else{
    $Saturday = strtotime($current_date . " previous saturday");
}
$Friday =  strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $Saturday) . " next friday");    
echo "This Reporting Week:&nbsp;" . date("m/d/Y", $Saturday) . " to " . date("m/d/Y", $Friday) . "<br/>";   
echo "<br/><br/>"   ;

#------------ NOT WORKING ----------------------
#not working
$previous_week_friday = strtotime('-1 week', strtotime($Friday));
$previous_week_friday = date("m/d/Y", $previous_week_friday);

$previous_week_saturday = strtotime('-1 week', strtotime($Saturday));
$previous_week_saturday = date("m/d/Y", $previous_week_saturday);

echo "Previous Reporting Week:&nbsp;" . date("m/d/Y", $previous_week_friday) . " to " . date("m/d/Y", $previous_week_saturday) . "<br/>";   
echo "<br/><br/>"
```

?>

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not working correctly?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`Hello again :-)`

Well $Friday and $Saturday is already integer in UNIX time so all you have to do is subtract one week in seconds. (60 x 60 x 24 x 7).

```
//#------------ WORKING -------------------------
$current_date = "08/25/2017";

if(date("l", strtotime($current_date)) == "Saturday"){
    $Saturday = strtotime($current_date);
}else{
    $Saturday = strtotime($current_date . " previous saturday");
}
$Friday =  strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $Saturday) . " next friday");    
echo "This Reporting Week:&nbsp;" . date("m/d/Y", $Saturday) . " to " . date("m/d/Y", $Friday) . "<br/>";   
echo "<br/><br/>\n"   ;

//#------------ NOW IT'S WORKING ----------------------

$previous_week_friday = date("m/d/Y", $Friday-3600*24*7);
$previous_week_saturday = date("m/d/Y", $Saturday-3600*24*7);

echo "Previous Reporting Week:&nbsp;" . $previous_week_friday . " to " . $previous_week_saturday . "<br/>";   
echo "<br/><br/>";
```

https://3v4l.org/0gj40

---

The reason you get the output you do is because you try to use strtotime on a UNIX value.
As the name of the function says, "string to time".
A UNIX value is not string, it's integer. So it fails and becomes 0.
The 0 is then used in the date function and you get 1970.
And probably you or the server is west of GMT so you get a negative value due to timezone thus 1969 ....